# What's the difference between passing span<T> and std::array as arguments?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

In his [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rp-typesafe), Bjarne Stroustrup recommends using span when passing arrays by reference. Why not just pass a std::array object?

Comment: Probably for simplicity and to avoid code bloat from the template you would need to use to accept any size `std::array`.

Comment: The core guidelines are not owned exclusively by Stroustrup.

Answer (score 13):

1. Passing `std::array` by value would be *copying* them. The point of `gsl::span` is that the function taking them is referencing an existing array of data.
2. `gsl::span` is capable of taking arrays of runtime-defined sizes. `std::array` is fixed at compile-time.
3. `gsl::span` does not care what type owns the array; it's just a pointer+size. So a `span`-based interface can be fed data from `std::vector`, `QVector`, and many other types. A `std::array` based interface *requires* that you use that specific container.

Comment: Thanks! On a similar note, why not pass a beginning and end iterator as arguments?

Comment: Because that would be two parameters. It would also require that your function be a *template* function. Functions that take iterator pairs can act on a wide variety of ranges, including in many cases stream iterators. Functions that act on `spans` can *only act* on a contiguous array of values.

Comment: @JoeHuang Because of [P.3: Express intent](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#p3-express-intent). One `span` object is self contained, having two iterators leaves the question if they are related and how.